# image goes off-positon on mobile

Tags: html, image, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to build a slider. And i positioned the directional nav buttons across the images, but when I go to mobile view, the buttons go way off, here is a section of code,

```
<div class="design container">
    <section class="subcontainer">
        <h2>
            I love to <span id="purple">design</span> beautiful websites and making<br> my code as good as it can 
        </h2>

        <div class="slider">

            <div class="slide"> 
               <img src="images/charity.jpg" width="100%">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/doveyjean.jpg" width="100%">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/1.jpg" width="100%">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="slider-nav">
          <div class="directional-buttons"> 
            <img class="backward" src="images/backward.png" width="8%">
            <img class="forward" src="images/forward.png" width="8%">
          </div>


            <!-- dots -->
            <ul>
                <li class="active"></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="button">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/more.png"></a>
        </div>

    </section>
</div>
```

here is the css, fyi I used css reset:

```
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
} 

header,section {
    height: 100%;
}

.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }  

.subcontainer {
    width: 93.75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}     

.design{
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 3%;
    height: 140vh;
}

.design h2{
    font-size: 1.75em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 4%; 
    line-height: 1.3;
}

#purple {
    color: #6600ff;
}

.slider{
  padding-top: 3%;
}

.slide{
    display: none;
}

.slide:first-child {
    display: block;
}

.button {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.slider-nav{
    height: 10%;
}

.slider-nav ul{
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -55px;
}

.slider-nav li{
    list-style: none;
    background-color: black;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.slider-nav li.active{
    background-color: #0060ff;
}

.directional-buttons{
    position: relative;
    top: -350%;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.forward{
    float: right;
}
```

I'm posting screenshot of the design,

[desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MryP.jpg)

[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xAEY.png)

how do I always keep the directional buttons at the vertical center of the slider and the dots below the slider? any type of suggestions are appreciated, and if the measures are suggested in percentage that would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put div `.directional-buttons` in the div slider to see that like this:

```
<div class="slider">

            <div class="slide">
                <img src="../a.jpg" style="height: 50vw;width: 100%;" width="">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/doveyjean.jpg" width="100%">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="images/1.jpg" width="100%">
            </div>
            <div class="directional-buttons">
                <img class="backward" src="images/backward.png" width="8%">
                <img class="forward" src="images/forward.png" width="8%">
            </div>
        </div>
```

And add this styles:

```
.slider {
   position: relative;
}

.directional-buttons {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: if I put -10% then it goes really down below, i've put -40% to get it to where I want but then the problem comes back. and what about the directional buttons?

Comment: I changed the answer, Please test that and let me know the result please.

Comment: it kinda works..but still gradually goes off positon when I shrink the browser

Comment: *goes off positon* you mean goes top again?

Comment: yeah..and as it gradually changes position when i shrink the browser, you have to add a lot of media queries, which isn't a good solution.

Comment: hey I didn't notice the html part. it's working now. Thanks!